# When to reject the null of no significant dependence between two variables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

[image]

For the first question I calculate the sample correlation coefficient, so r=0.3987866 then I calculate t=1.229972759 and as |t|<2.306 (which is the t-critical) we don't reject the null hypothesis (H0) at the 5% level. Therefore, there is no significant dependance between the lead and iron levels.

For question (b), we need |t|>2.306 in order to reject the null hypothesis at the 5% level and a sample size n=10. At the end I found |r|>0.6319 so the hypothetical values of the sample correlation are inside [-1,-0.6319]U[0.6319,1].

Are my answers correct? Also, what is your intuition for this test?